# Newtonsoft JSON.net deserialization error where fields in JSON change order

Tags: c#, json.net

This is a WCF service getting requests from android devices. 
Same request works from Lollipop devices, not from jellybean devices, because jellybean arranges the JSON differently on creation.

The exception:

> *Unexpected token when deserializing object: String. Path 'SearchFilters.config.$type', line 1, position 212.*

Non working Json:

```
{
    "DeviceType": 2,
    "SearchFilters": {
        "config": {
            "$values": [
                {
                    "Collection": {
                        "DeviceType": 2
                    },
                    "Category": ""
                }
            ],
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Yoosh.SharedClasses.YooshConfig, YooshSharedClassesDll]], mscorlib"
        }
    },
    "RequestingUserId": "66666666-6666-6666-6666-666666666666",
    "APIKey": "xxx"
}
```

Working Json:

```
{
    "APIKey": "xxx",
    "DeviceType": 2,
    "RequestingUserId": "66666666-6666-6666-6666-666666666666",
    "SearchFilters": {
        "config": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Yoosh.SharedClasses.YooshConfig, YooshSharedClassesDll]], mscorlib",
            "$values": [
                {
                    "Category": "",
                    "Collection": {
                        "DeviceType": 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Some fields are in a different order.. Thats the only difference.

The C# class:

```
public class QueryParameters 
{
    BaseParameters m_baseParameters;
    Guid m_gRequestingUserId;
    Dictionary<string, object> m_SearchFilters;

    [DataMember]
    public  string APIKey
    {
        get { return m_baseParameters.APIKey; }
        set { m_baseParameters.APIKey = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public  BaseParameters.YooshDeviceType DeviceType
    {
        get { return m_baseParameters.DeviceType; }
        set { m_baseParameters.DeviceType = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public  string DeviceId
    {
        get { return m_baseParameters.DeviceId; }
        set { m_baseParameters.DeviceId = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid RequestingUserId
    {
        get { return m_gRequestingUserId; }
        set { m_gRequestingUserId = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> SearchFilters
    {
       get { return m_SearchFilters; }
        set { m_SearchFilters = value; }
    }
}
```

Json.net version: 6.0.8

Comment: $type is special.  I don't think you can reorder that one.  It is what Newtonsoft Json uses to determine which C# object to create when deserializing.  Since you have a Dictionary<string,object>, it probably needs $type to figure out what type of object to create.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570510

Comment: `66666666-6666-6666-6666-666666666666` - the ID of the Beast

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set [`JsonSerializerSettings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_MetadataPropertyHandling.htm).

According to the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMetadataPropertyHandling.htm):

> This sample deserializes JSON with MetadataPropertyHandling set to ReadAhead so that metadata properties do not need to be at the start of an object.
>
> ```
>  string json = @"{
>   'Name': 'James',
>   'Password': 'Password1',
>   '$type': 'MyNamespace.User, MyAssembly'
> }";
>
> object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
> {
>     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
>     // $type no longer needs to be first
>     MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
> });
> ```

Note that this setting will [impact performance](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MetadataPropertyHandling.htm).

Finally, when using `TypeNameHandling`, do take note of this caution from the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see *[TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182)*.

Comment: Thanks, i'll test it after the weekend but i'm pretty sure this will work : ] 
Will update if not.