# Deserializing foreign json string with $type keyword which is not at the beginning

Tags: c#, json.net

I am deserializing a foreign json string (so no control over the structure). The foreign json uses "serializer" as discriminator. I am making this conform to json.net with `var json = str.Replace("\""serializer"\": \"", "\"$type\": \"");` as advised here: [JSON.Net - Change $type field to another name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490345/json-net-change-type-field-to-another-name)

The problem is, that in the foreign json string the "serializer" is not in the beginning but all properties are sorted alphabetically, json.net throws an exception on deserializing because it only recognizes the "$type" keyword if it is the first property in the string.

Any idea how I could deserialize this?

Comment: why don't you just deserialize it as is? how does the json look like? what happen if you don't replace the serializer string?

Comment: @Steve the $type keyword is used to include type information when serializing JSON and read type information so that the correct type is created when deserializing JSON. Usage of the $type keyword is required when using polymorphism. Read more here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: Use the same json framework as the source.

Comment: @AndréSanson, not possible as this would be a java framework.

Comment: So by chaging `serializer` to `$type`will never work indeed, you need to do a custom deserialization using `JsonConverter`.

Comment: @AndréSanson any other idea? I wanted to avoid that. In case you don't, do you have an example at hand by any chance?

Comment: You could set `MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead` as shown in [Newtonsoft JSON.net deserialization error where fields in JSON change order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29493292/3744182).

Comment: Or, write a custom converter as shown in [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182), [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528648/3744182) or [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

As the user dbc suggested, using MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead in the settings will solve the issue.

More here: [Newtonsoft JSON.net deserialization error where fields in JSON change order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493292/newtonsoft-json-net-deserialization-error-where-fields-in-json-change-order)

Comment: Are you sure this will work? You said it was from a java system and their naming convention is different from c#, eg: `com.stackoverflow.etc` as the package name.

Comment: @AndréSanson - it will if they've also written a custom `ISerializationBinder`.

Comment: @AndréSanson, yes it works and I didn't use ISerializationBinder. I replace the "$type" keyword with "serializer" and the other way round with str.Replace() and MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead reads ahead, meaning it's no problem if the "serializer" keyword wasn't in the first place (which is like never the case because it is sorted alphabetically and "s" is far from at the beginning of the alphabet), in case you are interested, check it here: https://github.com/helium-party/radixdlt-net/tree/master/HeliumParty.RadixDLT/src/HeliumParty.RadixDLT.Core/Serialization/Json